# How to add 1 day to the given parameter date? Got `java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date` error

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to add 1 day to a given parameter date.

In *Jaspersoft Studio* I have the following parameter

```
$P{datestart}
Class: java.sql.Date
Default value expression: new Date()

$V{datev}
Class: java.sql.Date
Expression: new java.sql.Date($P{datestart}.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000)
```

Then I use `$V{datev}` in the report.

Output error:

```
Error evaluating expression for source text: 
new java.sql.Date($P{datestart}.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000)  
java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

I tried different expressions but with no luck

```
Change $v{datev} to new java.util.Date($P{datestart}.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000).
Change $P{datestart} to: new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date())
```

Does anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Post the `.jrxml` content, if permissible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the definition of `$P{datestart}` parameter is wrong.

The expression `new java.sql.Date($P{datestart}.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000)` is valid if the *datestart* parameter has *java.util.Date* or *java.sql.Date* type.
As you probably know, the [*java.sql.Date*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) class is a subclass of [*java.util.Date*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

This *Java* code is working well:

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
new java.sql.Date(date.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000);

java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
new java.sql.Date(sqlDate.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000);
```

Try to change the type of *datestart* or even of both (parameter and variable).

At least you need to fix initialization of *datestart* parameter.

There is no `java.sql.Date()` (without parameters) constructor. Looks like you are using expression which has analogue of *Java* code like this:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.util.Date(); // not even compile. Got incompatible types: java.util.Date cannot be converted to java.sql.Date
```

This declaration will be valid for `$P{datestart}` of `java.sql.Date`:

```
<parameter name="datestart" class="java.sql.Date">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime())]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```